# Gesture Recognise + Alert View

Tags: ios7, uigesturerecognizer, alertview

I need to implement an app who recognise gesture (single/double tap, pan,pinch, rotation, swipe) and display an alert view.Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s iOS Developer Library contains what you are searching for. For gesture recognition, e.g., take a look at the following page: [Event handling guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html); AlertViews can be found in the [UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html)

Without having a more specific question, I cannot help you any further.